# Make can't find

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, path, clang, ld

I try to compile [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/) with support for [CLBlast](https://github.com/CNugteren/CLBlast) using CLBlast from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

MacPorts mainly uses /opt. When I search for clblast there I get this result

```
/opt % find . -iname '*clblast*'
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_copy_fast
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xger
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_routine_xtrsv
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xgemv
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xgemm
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xdot
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_invert
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_routine_xgemm
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_copy_pad
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xgemm_direct
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_transpose_pad
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xaxpy
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_transpose_fast
./local/bin/clblast_tuner_xconvgemm
./local/include/clblast.h
./local/include/clblast_c.h
./local/include/clblast_half.h
./local/include/clblast_netlib_c.h
./local/var/macports/software/clblast
./local/var/macports/software/clblast/clblast-1.5.3_0.darwin_22.x86_64.tbz2
./local/var/macports/registry/portfiles/clblast-1.5.3_0
./local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/math/clblast
./local/lib/libclblast.dylib
./local/lib/pkgconfig/clblast.pc
./local/lib/cmake/CLBlast
./local/lib/cmake/CLBlast/CLBlastConfig-macports.cmake
./local/lib/cmake/CLBlast/CLBlastConfig.cmake
./local/lib/libclblast.1.dylib
./local/lib/libclblast.1.5.3.dylib
```

When I compile I get this result:

```
% WHISPER_CLBLAST=1 make -j
(a lot of debug info deleted)
c++ -I. -I./examples -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -fPIC -pthread examples/quantize/quantize.cpp examples/common.cpp examples/common-ggml.cpp ggml.o ggml-opencl.o whisper.o -o quantize -L/opt/local/lib/ -framework Accelerate -lclblast -lOpenCL
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bench] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [quantize] Error 1
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The Makefile does have an LDFLAGS parameter, which is empty by default. I have tried several values, mostly similar to

```
LDFLAGS  = -L/opt/local/lib/
```

to no avail.

**How do I change my Makefile so it finds the appropriate CLBlasts libraries?**

There is no configure-file.

Comment: `ld: library not found for -lOpenCL`: where is the `OpenCL` library? Did you search for `libOpenCL.*`?